# System navigation bar overlay by custom keyboard

Tags: java, android

I am creating Android custom keyboard. Now My keyboard overlay the System navigation bar. I want to show the keyboard above System navigation bar.

My code:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        KeyboardView keyboardView = (KeyboardView) viewContainer.findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);
        this.keyboardView = keyboardView;
        this.keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        this.keyboardView.setEnabled(true);
        this.keyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
        this.keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(listener2);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        frameLayout.addView(viewContainer, lp);
        //viewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewContainer.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mActivity, R.anim.down_to_up));
```

KeyboardView.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#88000000" />

    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:keyBackground="@drawable/keyboard_key"
        android:keyTextColor="@color/white"
        android:keyTextSize="@dimen/sp_32"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</FrameLayout>
```

My screen op:
[image]

Please give some idea to resolve the issue.

Comment: does adding another view there overlap the navigation bar?

Comment: which view? Need to add new one? Or already existing one.?

Comment: add a button instead of the keyboard and check if the overlapping thing happens

Comment: For the time being I calculate the bottom navigation bar height and set that height for the frame layout bottom margin. Working fine. But I need to do this without setting margin. I will try and update with the answer..